# A Proof of Tukey's Inequality

Tags: unbiased-estimator, probability-inequalities, point-estimation, minimum-variance

Suppose that $W_1,W_2,...,W_n$ are uncorrelated unbiased estimators of a parameter $\theta$.

Consider $W=\sum_{i=1}^na_iW_i$ such that $E(W)=\theta$ and $Var(W_i)=\sigma^2_i$, where the $a_i$'s are constants. So it is trivial to see that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$. Call all such unbiased estimators $W$ "linear unbiased estimators" of $\theta$.

Let $W^{\star}$ be the linear unbiased estimator having minimum variance. It is easy to see, by a simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, that $W^{\star}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nW_i/\sigma_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(1/\sigma_i^2)}$ and $Var(W^{\star})=\dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}$. The corresponding optimal weights are $a_i^{\star}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}$.

Let $W'$ be **any other** linear unbiased estimator of $\theta$ such that $a_i\geq0$ for all $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$.

Then Tukey's Inequality is: $\dfrac{Var(W')}{Var(W^{\star})}\leq\dfrac{1}{1-\lambda^2}$ where $\dfrac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}=\dfrac{b_{\max}}{b_{\min}}$, with $b_{\max}=\max_i(\dfrac{a_i}{a_i^{\star}})$ and similarly $b_{\min}=\min_i(\dfrac{a_i}{a_i^{\star}})$, $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$.

How can this inequality be proved?

Answer (score 1):

See https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-19/issue-1/Approximate-Weights/10.1214/aoms/1177730297.full?tab=ArticleLinkCited or the Casella&Berger's "Statistical Inference". And here is a type-up.

$
\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{\left ( #1 \right )}
\newcommand{\curly}[1]{\left \{ #1 \right \} }
\newcommand{\squared}[1]{\left [ #1 \right ]}
$
Let us view the given $a_i$'s as follows:
fix $\lambda \in [0,1]$, given $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^k \subset [-1,1]$, put $b_i = a_i^*(1+\lambda t_i)$
and $a_i = \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k b_j}^{-1}b_i$.
In this format, the conditions $a_i \geqslant 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i = 1$ are satisfied
while the sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^k$ remains arbitrarily given.
We have, remarking that variance is additive in case of zero covariance:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        & \text{Var} \bracket{ \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^kb_j}^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^k b_i W_i} 
        = \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^kb_j}^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^k b_i^2\sigma_i^2
        \\&= \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^*(1+\lambda t_j)}^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^k (a_i^*)^2 (1+\lambda t_i)^2 \sigma_i^2
        \\& = \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^*(1+\lambda t_j)}^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^k \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\sigma_j^2}}^{-2} 
        \frac{1}{\sigma_i^4} (1+\lambda t_i)^2 \sigma_i^2
        \\& = \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^*(1+\lambda t_j)}^{-2} \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\sigma_j^2}}^{-1} 
        \sum_{i=1}^k a_i^* (1+\lambda t_i)^2 
        \\& = \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^*(1+\lambda t_j)}^{-2} \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\sigma_j^2}}^{-1} 
        \squared{1+2\lambda \sum_{i=1}^ka_i^*t_i + \lambda^2 \sum_{i=1}^k a_i^*t_i^2}
        \\& = \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^*(1+\lambda t_j)}^{-2} \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\sigma_j^2}}^{-1} 
        \squared{\bracket{1+ \lambda \sum_{j=1}^k a_j^*t_j}^2 + \lambda^2 \sum_{j=1}^k a_j^*t_j^2
            - \lambda^2 \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^*t_j}^2}
        \\& = \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\sigma_j^2}}^{-1} \curly{1+
            \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^*(1+\lambda t_j)}^{-2}\lambda^2\squared{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^*t_j^2
            - \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^*t_j}^2}} 
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

Put $T = \sum_{j=1}^k a_j^*t_j$. We now implement:

\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{j=1}^k a_j^* t_j^2 \leqslant 1
\end{equation*}

We have proved that:

\begin{equation*}
    \text{Var}(W) = \text{Var} \bracket{ \bracket{\sum_{j=1}^kb_j}^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^k b_i W_i} \leqslant 
    \text{Var}(W^*) \squared{1+ \frac{\lambda^2(1-T^2)}{(1+\lambda T)^2}}
\end{equation*}

If $f(T) = \frac{1-T^2}{(1+\lambda T)^2}$, then the equation $f'(T)=0$ has a unique solution $T=-\lambda$.
Taking $T=0$ for instance would yield that $T=-\lambda$ is a maximum. Therefore, plug in $T=-\lambda$ yields:

\begin{equation*}
    \text{Var}(W') \leqslant \frac{\text{Var}(W^*)}{1-\lambda^2}  
\end{equation*}

It is left to show that $\lambda$ defined in the problem is in the range $[0,1]$.
But directly solving for $\lambda$ in the given condition will yield:

\begin{equation*}
    \lambda = \frac{b_{\max}-b_{\min}}{b_{\max}+b_{\min}}
\end{equation*}

This completes the proof.